# How to convert List<bool> of 64 values to an Int64 in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have a list with 64 bool values:

```
List<bool> list;
```

and I want to convert these bool values to an `Int64` from `dart:ffi`, which according to its documentation:

> Represents a native signed 64 bit integer in C.
>
> Int64 is not constructible in the Dart code and serves purely as
> marker in type signatures.

**How do I convert a list of 64 bools to an Int64 where each bit is one of the bool values from the list?**

Comment: Can you give an example of 64 bool values and what number you expect? This has something to do with endianness and the order which the bools should be parsed.

Comment: @julemand101 endianness is not important here, I just need in the same order of the list. So `[0,1,1,0,...]` would be the integer `0110...`

Comment: Assuming that each `bool` is in order of most significant bit to least, you should be able to just iterate over the list and left-shift and OR with an accumulated result on each iteration (and not worry about endianness). `int` in Dart is already 64-bit for non-web platforms.

Comment: @jamesdlin something like this: `myInteger>>i = list[i]`? How can I set each individual bit of an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Note that `int` is signed in Dart.

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  final random = Random();
  final booleans = List.generate(64, (_) => random.nextBool());
  final number = toIntFromBoolList(booleans);

  print(booleans.map((e) => e ? '1' : '0').join());
  // 0010110101001000101010000100011111111010011110010110110101100011

  print(number);
  // 3263042957128330595

  print(number.toRadixString(2).padLeft(64, '0'));
  // 0010110101001000101010000100011111111010011110010110110101100011
}

int toIntFromBoolList(List<bool> booleans) {
  var number = 0;

  for (final bool in booleans) {
    number = number << 1;
    if (bool) {
      number = number | 1;
    }
  }

  return number;
}
```